# PHP5 + PostgreSQL - pg_fetch_row() returning string not array

Tags: php, postgresql, row, fetch, pg

PHP5 + PostgreSQL (ubuntu 12.04) according to the doco returns an array for pg_fetch_row().  By my test results indicate that it's returning a string, is there some configuration option for this?

```
$db = openDatabase(<blah>);
$query = "SELECT (id,serial,tag) FROM devices ORDER BY tag ASC";
$result = pg_query($db,$query);
if ($result)
{
    while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result))
        echo "IN: $row[0] - $row[1] - $row[2]";
}
```

I expect to see

```
IN: <value> - <value> - <value>
```

But I get

```
IN: (<value>,<value>,<value>) - -
```

I guess this means pg_fetch_row() is returning a string not an array?!

e.g. the actual run:

```
IN: (10,7426573,________) - - 
IN: (7,6862,FMUX-TAG) - - 
IN: (9,6914082,L6) - -
```

It seems a simple problem, but I can't find an answer.
I know I can parse the result, but that's kludgey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `SELECT (id,serial,tag)` into `SELECT id,serial,tag` and you're done.

Comment: that's it.  Thanks.  So it was PostgreSQL (well my syntax), not PHP.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple - just remove brackets from SELECT statement, like this:

```
$query = "SELECT id,serial,tag FROM devices ORDER BY tag ASC";
```

otherwise it is a string in output.